# Require/Include and Undefined Variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, include, require

SOLVED: The error had nothing to do with require or include. It was completely unrelated to the question. Sorry about that. :(

I thought I had an understanding of require/include until now. I have a file named `file_one` that has something like this, `$user_data = return_user_data_as_array()`. My second file `file_two`, calls `$user_data`. Now, when I do a `include 'file_two.php'` into the `file_one` page after the functions and variables have been called, the page returns with `undefined variable user_data`. I thought that if you include/require a file into your php code it would pick up any variables written in the original file? How would I fix this?

Edit: I also want to mention that although the undefined variable error is popping up on my screen, the "undefined" variables are correctly echoed out.

File One

```
//this require_once holds the function user_data()

require_once 'core/init.php';

$user_id = 1;

$profile_data = user_data($mysqli, $user_id); 

//this calls file two
require_once 'file_two.php';
```

File Two or file_two.php

```
echo $profile_data['full_name'];
```

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that although the variables are undefined, they are still echoed correctly on screen.

Comment: I don't get that at all, but I may not be doing what you're doing. You should paste some example reproduction code, and let us know what version of PHP you're using.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the function is also called from a require_once at the very top of the script, but I don't think that has anything to do with it, because if that wasn't working then my page wouldn't render at all so I assumed that the error referred to the second require_once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer had nothing to do with the problem in the question. The code in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is to have your include before not after the function call. Also just include the function and then call it in file two.

Comment: So I should have include 'file_two.php' before the variable $user_data is declared?

Comment: @AlexP hmm, Not sure what is meant there. Elaborate?

Comment: @jason328 - no, the opposite. Include 'file_two.php' AFTER the variable $user_data is declared.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have an error elsewhere on the page. If you're defining the variable outside of a function or class and you're including the file that uses it after it's been defined it should work fine:

**file_one.php**

```
<?php
function return_user_data_as_array(){
    return array('name'=>'BenD');
}

$user_data = return_user_data_as_array();

include('file_two.php');
?>
```

**file_two.php**

```
<?php
print_r( $user_data );
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => BenD
)
```

This should all work fine. Your error is probably arising elsewhere (for instance, you might be calling `$user_data` from inside a function without specifying `global $user_data`, or you're calling `$user_data` somewhere in file_one.php accidentally?)

### EDIT

Now that you've shown some code, I imagine that the problem is that `user_data()` isn't returning an array that includes the `full_name` key. Try `print_r($profile_data)` to see what the array looks like. I'm guessing that the problem lies in what's being returned from `user_data()` (if anything! make sure it includes a `return $x` clause in there! I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out a logical error when the only problem was that my function didn't return anything)

Comment: The function returns the information correctly. I know this because before I outsourced the code in file_two from file_one, it was working fine with no errors produced.

Comment: In your question, what do you mean "the undefined variable error is popping up on my screen"... could you provide the specific error message (pasted or screen-shot?)

Comment: Ah, I see you got it sorted out. Apparently I had it correct until you posted your code and I tried to get too clever in the "EDIT" section ... see, everyone always says "post your code", but see where it got us this time? :)

Comment: Yeah, I apologize about that.

Comment: :) no worries... my last question ended the same way